# NSView (Content View) as firstResponder

Tags: objective-c, nsview, first-responder

I have a Content View that I use in my preferences nib. 
I use a method to change the font of a NSTextView in my app.

This Content View has to be set as firstResponder to get messages from my changeTextFont: method, but since it's not a window it doesn't have a firstResponder. As a result, it does not change the text font at all... does anyone have a workaround for this ?

Thanks a bunch guys.

Comment: I am not sure that your content view must be first responder for what you are trying to do... could you explain why you think so? sorry if  I am missing something obvious in your explanation....

Comment: Sergio, have a look at this example (which is what I'm using): http://homepage.mac.com/mmalc/CocoaExamples/ControlledPreferences.zip. It has a WINDOW as firstResponder, not a content view, so I'd like to adapt this to my needs.

Comment: nobody can help me out ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I could make the sample project work without specifying `[self window]` as first responder. What I did was:

1. in `(void)changeTextFont:(id)sender`, I replaced the statement:

   ```
   [[self window] makeFirstResponder:[self window]];
   ```

   with lines:

   ```
   [[NSFontManager sharedFontManager] setAction:@selector(changeMyFont:)]; 
   [[NSFontManager sharedFontManager] setTarget:self];    //-- this seems to be not mandatory, but I mention it because your case could be different
   ```
2. I renamed `changeFont:` to `changeMyFont:`:

   ```
   - (void)changeMyFont:(id)sender
   {
   ```

With these changes, the font is correctly updated in the example content view.

I don't know if it will work for you, because in the end you are trying to use this code in a different context, but I hope that it will. I would suggest you to first try and modify the sample project so that you can get confident with my solution and then move it to your project to check whether it also works there.

Comment: Sergio, thanks for your answer but that doesn't work. I have no idea why, but it doesn't...

Comment: Put a breakpoint in `changeMyFont`, you'll see it is called. Also, have a look at the image I posted...

Comment: Well if it works for you with a Content View, it should work for me too... Could I see more of your code? Maybe I'm missing something...

Comment: I have rewritten and clarified my answer, I hope it helps.